# How to put some text after an algorithm?

Tags: floats, positioning

I need to have some text place AFTER an algorithm. Here is an MVE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
Some text before the algortihm.
\begin{algorithm}   
    \caption {An algorithm.}
    \begin{algorithmic}[H]
        \Function{theAlgorithm}{} : 
        \State test
        \EndFunction\\
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
Some more text after the algorithm.
\end{document}
```

The output is formated this way:

```
Some text before the algorithm. Some text after the algorithm.
---THE ALGORITHM---
```

I want to have:

```
Some text before the algorithm.
---THE ALGORITHM---
Some text after the algorithm.
```

I have tried to put it in a figure with different placement constraints 
but so far nothing works.

Comment: Algorithm is a float environnement. You should see this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm) loads [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) which provides the `[H]` float specifier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
Some text before the algortihm.
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{An algorithm.}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Function{theAlgorithm}{} : 
    \State test
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
Some more text after the algorithm.

\end{document}
```

Note that it's used with `algorithm`, not `algorithmic` (which is provided by [`algpseudocode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)).

In general, let floats do what they do best... float. However, it seems that you're using the [`exam` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam), which might require some restrictions in terms of place. Regardless, considering reading the FAQ [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764).

Comment: I really needed ths same preambule. see my answer.

Comment: @Eric: That doesn't change my answer. [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) is loaded by `algpseudocode`. Also, the float options doesn't care whether you're using [`exam`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) or `article`.

Comment: I agree, I changed the question to better reflect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my code I included \usepackage{fixltx2e} and that was prohibiting me to put the [H] options. After I removed the package and the error is gone and the text is displayed correctly.

Comment: So then your original post does not contain a "minimal example" as you stated.

Comment: @Werner Yes but I didnt know at the time what was causing the problem! Dont you think it is important for people to know that this package causes problem?

Comment: Since "LaTeX 2015", [`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) does nothing but issue a warning. If this is the main cause of your problem, you need to [update your TeX distribution](http://goo.gl/CqWB1).